# setTimeOut inside for loop when delay is 0 seconds

Tags: javascript, scope

After reading a few links as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026553/settimeout-inside-a-for-loop) and [here](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/) I'm having trouble to understand why `Ver2` prints out `5 5 5 5`, rather than `1 2 3 4`

`Ver1`

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000)  // 5 5 5 5
}
```

`Ver2`

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0)  // 5 5 5 5
}
```

`Ver3`

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000)  // 1 2 3 4 
}
```

In `Ver3`, since `let` is block scoped.

1. i = 1, setTimeout(() => console.log(1), 1000) event is queued
2. i = 2, setTimeout(() => console.log(2), 1000) event is queued
3. i = 3, setTimeout(() => console.log(3), 1000) event is queued
4. i = 4, setTimeout(() => console.log(4), 1000) event is queued
   Hence, it prints out 1 2 3 4 in sequence.

In `Ver2`, since `var` is function scoped.

1. i = 1, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0) event is queued (Since delay is 0, shouldn't this print out 1 immediately?
2. i = 2, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0) event is queued (prints out 2 immediately)
3. i = 3, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0) event is queued (prints out 3 immediately)
4. i = 4, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 0) event is queued (prints out4 immediately)
5. i = 5

After testing this out a couple of times, results consistently output `5 5 5 5` why is this the case?

```js
0ms   Start
1ms   i = 1, queued console.log(i) after 0ms(1) (Since this is executed immediately, it should print 1??)
2ms   i = 2, queued console.log(i) after 0ms(2)
3ms   i = 3, queued console.log(i) after 0ms(3)
4ms   i = 4, queued console.log(i) after 0ms(4)
5ms   i = 5
```

In `Ver1`, since var is function scoped

1. i = 1, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000) event is queued, wait for 1000ms
2. i = 2, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000) event is queued, wait for 1000ms
3. i = 3, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000) event is queued, wait for 1000ms
4. i = 4, setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000) event is queued, wait for 1000ms
5. i = 5
   After ~1000ms(or slightly over due to 4 queuing time), console should log `5 5 5 5`.

```js
0ms   Start
1ms   i = 1, queued console.log(i) after 1000ms(1)
2ms   i = 2, queued console.log(i) after 1000ms(2)
3ms   i = 3, queued console.log(i) after 1000ms(3)
4ms   i = 4, queued console.log(i) after 1000ms(4)
5ms   i = 5
1000ms console.log(i) when i = 5(1)
1001ms console.log(i) when i = 5(2)
1002ms console.log(i) when i = 5(3)
1003ms console.log(i) when i = 5(4)
```

Comment: My guess is setTimeout 0 adds a console.log to the next available event loop, basically JS is single threaded you've already set i to 5 by the time the callback is executed? Let me double check and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yes, I found setTimeOut(...,0) will defer the callback until main stack is empty. Useful link here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ. When does this main stack get cleared out tho? Assume you'd have modules wrapping nested functions, you'd have to wait for entire modules executed before this callback being executed??

Comment: i in your case is in the global scope, normally callback like this have their own parameters - I'm afk at the moment but have you tried simply passing i as a parameter to the function? setTimeout((i) => console.log(i), 1000)